# How to grep exim command output in terminal?

Tags: debian, grep, exim

I expected this command to print some lines containing "routed by" string:

```
root@localhost:~# exim -bt -d root@example.com | grep "routed by"
```

But it listed full `exim -bt -d root@example.com` command output. Which command would do what I excepted? The OS is Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output goes to stderr, so redirect it:

```
$ exim -bt -d root@example.com 2>&1|grep routed\ by
routed by amavis router
```